# Where is UIPasteboard physically located?

Tags: ios, security, backup, uipasteboard

Where are the contents of an app-specific UIPasteboard physically stored on a device?

Is this something which is backed-up when iTunes backs up the device?

So, in terms of security, would one want to encrypt data sent to the UIPasteboard?

Answer (score 2):

From [UIPasteboard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html):

> A pasteboard is a **named region of memory** where data can be shared.
>   There are two system pasteboards: the General pasteboard
>   (UIPasteboardNameGeneral) and the Find pasteboard
>   (UIPasteboardNameFind. You can use the General pasteboard for
>   copy-paste operations involving any kind of data; the Find pasteboard,
>   which is used in search operations, holds the most recent string value
>   in the search bar.

Info about app-specific pasteboards:

> Apps can also create pasteboards for their own use or for use by other
>   apps that have the same team ID. A pasteboard must be identified by a
>   unique name. You may also mark an app-specific pasteboard as
>   persistent, so that it continues to exist past the termination of the
>   app and past system reboots.

However, the documentation does not specify where the items are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your response;  I am wondering though if contents of these Pasteboards (if they are marked as persistent) are included with app data that is backed up through iTunes.